# How do I use more steps to approximate the boundary condition with NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following code:

```
weq = NDSolve[{
  D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}],
  u[0, t] == 0, u[2 Pi, t] == 0,
  u[x, 0] == Sin[x] + 1/3 Sin[5 x] + 1/9 Sin[25 x]},
  u, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, MaxStepFraction -> 1/500][[1, 1, 2]]
Plot[Sin[x] + 1/3 Sin[5 x] + 1/9 Sin[25 x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
Plot[weq[x, 0], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

This produces the following output:

[image]
[image]

These two plots should match, but NDSolve isn't sampling the boundary condition with a sufficiently high resolution for them to match. How can I tell NDSolve to sample the boundary condition with more points?

Answer (score 6):

By adding `Method->{FiniteElement,MeshOptions->MaxCellMeasure->0.01}` to `NDSolve`, the initial condition (i.c.) will match, but are you sure you want to solve your equation under these constraints? To solve a wave equation numerically, we *usually* need to set it as an initial-boundary value problem (IBVP), in your case you need one more i.c. e.g. `D[u[x, t], t]==0 /. t -> 0`. Actually, `NDSolve` will spit out `ivone` in *v9.0.1*, because it can only deal with IBVP of wave equation at that time.

`NDSolve` gives a result in *v10* or higher, because `"FiniteElement"` method is added since then and `NDSolve` will try to solve your problem as a boundary value problem (BVP). According to the **Details** of `NeumannValue`:

> …not specifying a boundary condition at all is equivalent to
>   specifying a Neumann 0 condition.

So when you only provide 3 conditions to solve the wave equation, `NDSolve` will think you've implicitly set the 4th b.c. as $\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}\Bigl{|}_{t=2\pi}=0$ i.e. your code is equivalent to

```
weq = NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + NeumannValue[0, t == 2 Pi], 
    u[0, t] == 0, u[2 Pi, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == Sin[x] + 1/3 Sin[5 x] + 1/9 Sin[25 x]}, 
   u, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},Method->FiniteElement][[1, 1, 2]]
```

`NDSolve` manages to find a solution under these conditions, but remember BVP for wave equation is a well known [ill-posed problem](http://math.nsc.ru/LBRT/u2/Survey%20paper.pdf). If it's not what you're trying to deal with, adding the missing i.c. and solve the problem as an IBVP is the correct way to go.

BTW, the `MaxStepFraction -> 1/500` doesn't have any effect in your case, it's an option for adjusting time step.