# Understanding `NeumannValue`

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

From this interesting question [Reveal the formal PDE of FiniteElement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225711/reveal-the-formal-pde-of-finiteelement)

```
op = -x D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] - D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] - 1;
{state} =NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{op == 0 ,DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True] },u, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]];
NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE[state]
```

I learned

$\left\{\nabla _{\{x,y\}}\cdot \left(-\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).\nabla _{\{x,y\}}u(x,y)\right)+\{1,0\}.\nabla _{\{x,y\}}u(x,y)-1\right\}$

that `NeumannValue` of this problem is `(-{{x, 0}, {0, 1}} . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]) . n` (thanks @user21 's comments)!

Trying to verify this knowledge , I solved examplary

```
U = NDSolveValue[{op == NeumannValue[0, x< 0] ,    
DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x > 0]}
, u, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], Method ->"FiniteElement"]
```

with `DirichletConditions x>0`and `NeumannValue x<0`on the boundary of `Disk[]`. Normalvector `n=#/Sqrt[# . #] &[{x, y}]` gives the formula

```
nv = Function[{x, y}, Evaluate[ 
{x Derivative[1, 0][U][x, y]
,Derivative[0, 1 ][U][x, y]} . (#/Sqrt[#. #] &[{x, y}]) ]]
```

for the  `NeumannValue`.

But

```
Show[{ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t],Sin[t],nv[Cos[t], Sin[t]]}, {t, 0,2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 500,BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},AxesLabel -> {"x","y", "NeumannValue"}, PlotRange -> All,RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x < 0]],     Graphics3D[{Opacity[.4],InfinitePlane[{{1, 0,0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}]}]
```

[image]

shows , that `NeumannValue`doesn't vanish as restricted .

What's wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Did you realize that your PDE has elliptic type at `x>0`, and hyperbolic type at `x<0`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks, no I didn't, but does it concern `NeumannValue` ?

Comment: Yes, actually you have 3 different equations. For the wave equation at x<0 you need 2 bc as minimum. For equation  `D[u[x,y],{y,2}]+1==0` at `x=0` you need also 2 bc at $y=\pm 1$, and for Poisson equation at x>0 you need Dirichlet at `x>0` and some bc at `x->0`.

Comment: As pointed out by Alex, there's a wave equation hidden in your toy example. Boundary value problem of Wave equation is ill-posed. As to ill-posed problem, you may want to read the first 2 sections of this paper: http://math.nsc.ru/LBRT/u2/Survey%20paper.pdf. BTW here's another example showing the ill-posedness of BVP of wave equation: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156651/1871

Comment: @xzczd Thank you, I'll elaborate the papers. Just one remark: I solved several problems concerning wave equation using Method Of Lines and FiniteElement without problems!

Comment: That's expected, initial-boundary value problem of wave equation is well-posed.

Comment: @xzczd That means my examplary problem can't be solved correctly with Finite Element method?

Comment: Not limited to FEM. None of those common numeric methods will work well on the problem, I'm afraid. For ill-posed problem/inverse problem, special techniques are needed. Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/216747/1871